# Faulty vulkan driver crashes program when querying device capabilities

Tags: c++, linux, graphics, driver, vulkan

I seem to have two drivers installed.

```
    driverID           = DRIVER_ID_MESA_RADV
    driverID           = DRIVER_ID_MESA_LLVMPIPE
```

In the default state my machine is when booting, my program segfaults in the following operation:

`physical_device.getQueueFamilyProperties();` (I am using the hpp header)

However if prior to running my program I do `export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json` my program runs without issue.

It seems as if the lavapipe implementation is crashing the program, especially since vulkaninfo shows this warning:

```
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_lvp.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
```

vkcube runs fine in all instances however. Is there a way to select the driver/loader on the program itself? i.e. not need to change an env var?

Comment: Lavapipe apparently does not work. Why not just use the `VkPhysicalDevice` you want to use. That is the programmatic way to do it...

Comment: I technically do that. However the way I do it is to query the devices for capabilities (e.g. how many queues it supports)... I assign a score and select the one with the best score. 

The problem is that lavapipe crashes when I try to call any device querying capabilities.

Comment: You could also just set the env variable programmatically as long as it is before `vkCreateInstance`.

Comment: Though you might want to just fix your install. Why do you have 32-bit drivers on 64-bit OS.

Comment: @krOoze I am not sure, this is a borderline pristine installation of Ubuntu hirsute. I only installed a few programs like vs code. Did not install new drivers or anything of the sort.

Comment: Would be far from first time a linux distro screwed up something. Exposing non-conformant driver is in of itself extremely unprofessional and violation of the Vulkan ecosystem. They think apps can read warnings??

Comment: Anyway, I would try to uninstall i386 version of the `mesa-vulkan-drivers` if it at least clears the ERRORs. `apt purge mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386`, I think...

Comment: `vulkaninfo` would also get all the props. I take it it crashes too? How did you get to the driver IDs. You could be blacklisting the physical device using that.

Comment: vulkaninfo and vkcube do not crash whatsoever. I am unsure why my program crashes when they don't.

Comment: That's interesting. `vulkaninfo` definitely queries stuff as well. What about `vkcubepp`? Maybe worth taking `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump` of your stuff up to the crash.